# Core Data not updating object in private Context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm really struggling with this issue:

I have an object saved in core data. I have a method which updates some properties of that object. I'm using that object's Managed Object Context from `obj.managedObjectContext`.

I change 2 properties: `obj.pending = YES` and `obj.body = 'text'`.
I then save the object back to Core Data as follows:

```
 if ([managedObjectContext save:&saveError]) {

            [persistenceController saveContextAndWait:YES completion:^(NSError *error) {
                 [OfflineManager postData];
            }];

        }
```

The `postData` method gets all objects from Core Data where the `obj.pending == YES` and posts the data. It's managedObjectContext is of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

My issue is as follows: The `obj.pending` seems to be updating but the `obj.body` is not. If I add a breakpoint to the app before it posts and restart the app, then the `obj.body` is correctly updated.

If this is a context issue why are some of the object properties' changes being seen and other not?

I've been hacking away at this for hours, any help would be most grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you explicitly save the store?  The managed object context that is connected to the store (isn't a child of some other context) will do that for you.

Comment: I'm using MDMCoreData - A collection of lightweight Core Data classes to manage my CD in my app.

Comment: @Avi do you think this could be the issue?

Comment: It's more likely that your issue is that the private context isn't being refreshed properly.  How is merging handled?  What is your context hierarchy?

Comment: @Avi, I'm not too sure about context hierarchy, I'm new to this library and Core Data. Merging - in the class thats handling the background post the merge policy is `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy`.    I changed this to `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` but it didn't help.          The MOC for that class is of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. The method saving the obj is also of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` - I've changed this as well but hasn't helped either.

Comment: Is the background context persistent, or is it created as-needed?

Comment: I'm getting the object from core data using the `NSManagedObjectID` - I think this could be causing the issue, if I use another property of the object it seems to work correctly, but unfortunately the `NSManagedObjectID` is the only unique ID of the object at this point where I need to get the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122440/discussion-between-avi-and-mrcurious).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Avi for the solution. The issue was with the persistent context and not having a merge handler to handle background contexts. My solution was to just create a new context every time for the `postData` method.